# Find a basis of ker $T$ and find a basis of im $T$ of $T: P_2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2,T(a+bx+cx^2)=(a,b)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Find a basis of ker $T$ and find a basis of im $T$ of $T: P_2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2,T(a+bx+cx^2)=(a,b)$

Comment: Where  do you get stucked in the problem?

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh I don't know how to do it at all.

Comment: @TaljanaD You can start from the definitions. What does $\ker T$ mean? What is a basis of a vector (sub)space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$ \text{ker } T = \{a+bx+cx^2 \in P_2| (a,b) = (0,0) \} = \{cx^2\ | c \in \mathbb{R}\} $. So, $\{ x^2 \}$ is a basis.

$\text{im } T = \{(a,b) | ax^2+bx+c \in P_2  \} = \{ (a,b) | a,b \in \mathbb{R}  \} = \mathbb{R}^2$. So, $\{(0,1), (1,0)\}$ is a basis.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

For kernel, think of what is the solution of $T(a+bx+cx^2)=(0,0)$, notice that $a$ and $b$ must be zero. There should be exactly one element in the basis of kernel of  $T$.

For the image, Noice that $T(1)=(1,0)$, $T(x)=(0,1)$. Can you construct the basis for the image of $T$?